# The symmetry of a geometirc circle associated to a riemannian metric

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-groups

Let $g=\sqrt{adx^2+bdxdy+cdy^2}$ be some Riemannian metric, where $a,b,c$ are positive constant numbers. That is to say $$(g)=\begin{pmatrix}a&b/2\\ \:\:\:b/2&c\end{pmatrix}. $$
Assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is the geometric circle associate to the Riemannian metric $g$, that is $\mathcal{C}$ is given by the folllwoing equation: $$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b/2\\ \:\:\:b/2&c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=1. $$

> My question is that what kinf of symmetry has $\mathcal{C}$, as $g$ is symmetric with respect to the diagonal?

Comment: You’re assuming $a,b,c$ all constant? Why are you calling this locus in a particular tangent plane “a geometric circle”?

Comment: Becaause for any point (x,y) belonging to \mathcal{C}, when I take the norm, it correpponds to one.

Comment: OK, as long as you understand this is in a fixed tangent plane, not actually in the surface. Since the metric is positive definite, this will be an ellipse in the plane (using the standard metric, not the induced metric).